# Compute the fraction of two functions in Fourier space and then apply inverse Fourier-transform

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I want to calculate the fraction of two functions in Fourier-space where the numerator is the Fourier-transform of a known function and the denominator depends on Fourier-space variables.

Specifically I want to implement what I calculated in WolframAlpha:
[image: Symbolic solution with WolframAlpha]

My attempt to implement this formula in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf

q = np.linspace(-2, 2,100)

Fu = np.fft.fft(np.exp(-q**2))

u = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Fu), d=0.1) # My attempt to calculate Fourier-space variable

Fu_proc = Fu/(1.0j*(u+1e-9)) # Add 1e-9 for numerical stability

Wq = np.fft.ifft(Fu_proc)
```

The result is very different from Wolfram's:

[image: My result vs WA result]

I guess the problem is that `u` is not what it should be. Note this is just a sanity-check problem, what I really want to implement is more complicated, but this simple example should work.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the FFT is the works with the periodic functions, you would need an FFT of length infinity in order to make it work. You could also calculate the improper integrals.

In this case we know is that dividing by `u` in the spectral domain is calculating the integral in `q` on the original domain. Doing this in the frequency domain analytically is very interesting but if you want to compute numerically for this case it seems to me that the best approach is to compute the integral in the original domain.